# Import an array using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a very simple 2D array in a file called synergy_data.json:

```
[
['2014-08-19',  2956],
['2014-07-19',  2038],
['2014-06-19',  1285],
['2014-05-19',  1383],
['2014-04-19',  1256],
['2014-03-19',  822],
['2014-02-19', 644],
['2014-01-19',  504],
['2013-12-19',  438],
]
```

I'm trying to call up that data using ajax:

```
data=[]
$.ajax({
    url: "/marquee/synergy_data.json",
    async: false,
    success: function(resultData) {
        data = resultData;
    }
});
console.log(data)
```

But the console only spits out "[]"

What am I doing wrong?

***Solution
A big thanks to @Quentin for solving this for me. I had two fatal flaws with my JSON: 1) I used single quotes and 2) I had an extra comma. I'll be sure to use JSONLint to check my arrays in the future! (I also removed the "async:false" for good measure.)

Comment: Don't use `async:false`, do the logic inside the callback or simply return a jQuery deferred and handle the callback later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON is invalid. The success function won't fire. The error function isn't defined. You end up accessing the array you originally assign to `data` and not the one from the JSON.

Strings in JSON must be quoted using `"` characters. `'` are not acceptable.

Commas are used to separate items in an array, not terminate them. Remove the trailing comma.

Comment: ouch. should have seen that. +1.

Comment: p.s. , would line breaks in json file would be 100% ok ?

Comment: Line breaks in JSON are fine so long as they aren't in the middle of strings.

Comment: Hey @Quentin, thanks for your answer, but I tried that, and it didn't work. I tried it with apostrophes, with double quotes, without quotes, and by replacing the dates with numbers. Still doesn't work. (But I'll use quotes in the future.)

Comment: You had another validation error. You should probably stop writing JSON by hand, or at least use a tool like JSON Lint.

Comment: @Quentin, I could kiss you!

Comment: Ah, I guess I didn't see your last sentence, @Quentin. That was the second issue.